# Visual Studio 2013 SQL Compact

Tags: sql, sql-server-ce

Has SQL compact been replaced in the new Visual Studio? I go to my data sources and try to connect to SQLCE database and I can't find that option anywhere. Is anyone else seeing the same thing?

Do I need to use VS2012 for SQLCE?

Comment: Yep, I was also having trouble seeing the CE option in VS2013.  I went with the accepted answer below - nice tool =)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [here](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/0e313dfd-be80-4afb-b5e9-6e74d369f7a1):-

> The SQL Server Compact Toolbox adds several features in concert with
>   Server Explorer to help your SQL Server Compact development efforts:
>   Explore!
>
> - Connect to SQL Server Compact 3.5 and 4.0 database files in **Visual Studio 2010, 2012 and 2013**
> - Lists all SQL Server Compact Data Sources defined in Server Explorer
> - Displays object properties in Properties window
> - Launch directly from Server Explorer
> - Explore all database objects: Tables, Columns, Indexes, Keys, Statistics, Merge Subscriptions, Sync Scopes
> - Remove invalid Data Sources from the Toolbox (and Server Explorer)
> - Rename tables

Comment: Seems like that's the only solution

Comment: Pat, let me know if you are missing ant features (EDMX generation coming very soon)

Comment: Does it let you create them?